# Can monero-wallet-cli tell me the one-time public keys (outputs) that belong(ed) to it?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-data, block-explorer, stealth-address

When viewing the data on a block explorer, how can I be sure which outputs are mine?  Due to Monero using stealth addresses, the block explorers show all the one-time public keys (which are the outputs owned by the address).  I would think my wallet would/could save the one-time public keys upon finding the ones that belonged to me.  I can't figure out how to do it, or if it can do it.

By the way, I'm curious about the inputs to a transaction and the outputs.  For example, the person/wallet who sent me Monero effectively created an output belonging to me, and that output is identified by its one-time public key.  Can my wallet spit out the one-time public key, so I can look at it on a block explorer?

Or, looking at it another way, what if I wait to spend an output, and I want to identify the one-time public key on the blockchain that's the real one I'm spending as an input to the transaction?  Is there another way to accomplish identifying my one-time public key input besides running `show_transfers`, figuring out which output was spent, and then tying the block heights together?  (Bear in mind, this method may become highly difficult/cumbersome in wallets with long histories.)

In short, how do I make `monero-wallet-cli` produce a list of the one-time public keys that it owns (ideally spent and unspent)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the public keys for your outputs with:

`incoming_transfers verbose`

For spent ones, or unspent ones, respectively:

`incoming_transfers verbose unavailable` or `incoming_transfers verbose available`

Verbose mode will also give you the key image for each output.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  That command provides two related pieces of information, namely the `tx id` and the `index`, but not the one-time public key (unless I'm missing something).  I guess what you're saying is I can use the index to identify the one-time public key.  moneroblocks.info doesn't reflect the index, that I've found. chainradar.com does show the index. explore.moneroworld.com does also.  Hm.

Comment: Ah, the default doesn't, sorry. It's: incoming_transfers verbose. I will amend.